# Bug of New .scrollPostion modifier in SwiftUI's ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

I have a scrollView with the new .scrollPosition modifier in my macOS. It seems to have some bugs.

first, It don't work in the preview.

second, When I add an item in my array, I want it to scroll to the newest item's position. Suppose the scroll indicator is already in the bottom. When I add an item, the scroll indicator will first go to the top, and scroll to the bottom. Here is my test code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct TextView2: View {
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Task> { task in
        task.status == DoingTaskStatus
    }) var tasks: [Task]
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var ctx: ModelContext
    
    @State private var newTaskID: UUID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                let task = Task(name: "newTask")
                ctx.insert(task)
                newTaskID = task.id
            } label: {
                Text("add")
            }
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(tasks) { task in
                        TestTaskList(task: task)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollPosition(id: $newTaskID)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TextView2()
        .modelContainer(previewContainer)
}
```

Is the scrollview's new API designed for iOS and iPods only? It just does't support well in the Mac, like the animation for example. How can I use animation with the new .scrollPosition modifier? And deal with the bug like the indicator's behavior I mentioned above.

Here is the video link I recorded for the bugs:
https://imgur.com/a/upE7rLj